# Importing checker texture from blender 2.93 to unity 2020.3

Tags: unity, blender

I have a checker texture made in a blender 2.93

[image]

which is created in such a way,
Material properties - new material - and on that material,
using two texture images and adding a checker texture node in between.

[image]

while importing this to unity I can't get texture with the material.

I tried path mode to copy and enable embed textures before exporting into .fbx file but it just extracted two separated images and only one of them can be assigned to the material.

Any solution for this much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created the node structure as required and then baked the texture

following several guidelines. after that used that image as a texture in the main project.

Baking of texture and using them as png instead of using node structure helps exporting materials and texture from blender to unity